# Not work true my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I want after click on link show alert box with tow option `ok` and `cancel`, if user click on button `ok` return it function is `true` and if click on button `cancel` return it function is `false`, problem is here that after click on link always return is `true`. How can fix it?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/

```
function myalert() {
    var result = true;
    var $alertDiv = $('<div class="alert">Do you want to delete this item?<button class="ok">ok</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></div>');
    $('body').append($alertDiv);
    $('.ok').click(function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'none');
        result = true;
    });
    $('.cancel').click(function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'none');
        result = false;
    });
    $alertDiv.fadeIn(100);
    $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'block');
    return result;
};

$('.iu').click(function () {
    alert(myalert());
    if (myalert() == true) {
        alert('ok')
    } else {
        alert('no')
    }
});
```

**Update:**

```
...
$('.iu').click(myalert)
function callback(result) {
    //
    if(result){
        alert(result);
        $('.image_upbg').each(function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass(unique())});
        var get_class = '.'+$(this).closest('div').attr('class');
        var get_val = $(this).closest('a').find('input').attr('value');
        //alert(get_val);
        var val = 'val_upimg1=' + get_val;
        $(get_class).fadeOut('slow');
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'delete_upimg',
                data: val,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                        $(get_class).fadeOut('slow');
                },
                "error": function (x, y, z) {
                    // callback to run if an error occurs
                    alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
                }
       });
    }else{
        alert('no')
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use javascript confirm instead of alert ?

Comment: I would like to customize it for myself, Like use from `direction: rtl;` or change button and ... how can solution above problem?

Comment: Then the solution provided by njreed would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep it structured like this, you could use a callback after the user responds.

http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/2/

```
function myalert() {
  ...do stuff here
        $('.ok').click(function () {
            callback(true);     // callback when user clicks ok
        });
        $('.cancel').click(function () {
            callback(false);    // callback when user clicks cancel
        });
}

$('.iu').click(myalert);

function callback(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

As suggested by Ben you could improve this by making the callback function a parameter to the first function to remove the tight coupling.

Comment: After click on button `ok` or `cancel` not work `fadeOut`, !!?

Comment: Using an alert() will block the browser. This was just copied from your original code for demo purposes. This will work if you do not use an alert. If you want to take the action *after* the fade is complete, you can pass the callback as a parameter to fadeOut().

Comment: Not work ajax call in `function callback(result) {...` what do i do? see:http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/7/

Comment: You probably need to pass the data parameter to the ajax call as a JSON object. For future reference, you should not use the comments section for further technical questions. Try to isolate your problem and post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

`myalert()` returns before `result` is set to `true` or `false`. To fix it I suggest having `myalert()` take a callback function as a parameter, and calling it inside the `click()` handlers within `myalert()`. The `.iu` event handler will then need to be split into two functions, one of which is the callback passed into `myalert()`.

Answer (score 0):

you are not waiting for the ok and cancel clicks so would always return true.

Modified the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/3/

```
function myalert() {
    var result = true;
        //var hide = $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        //var css = $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','none');
        var $alertDiv = $('<div class="alert">Do you want to delete this item?<button class="ok">ok</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></div>');
        $('body').append($alertDiv);

        $alertDiv.fadeIn(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','block');
        return result;
    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ok').live('click',function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','none');
        alert('ok');
    });

    $('.cancel').live('click',function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','none');
        alert('cancel');
    });

    $('.iu').click(function() {
        myalert();
    });
})
```

Comment: I want `$('.ok').live('click',function () {...` and `$('.cancel').live('click',function () {...` put in function `myalert()` and with run it in `$('.iu').click(function() {...` use from it. how is this?